# $("'" + foo + "'") vs $(foo)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code that has been working since it's beginning, well over a two months.  The selectors had dynamic content, stored in the variable `newClasses`.   My code used to be `$("'" + newClasses + "'")`, and about a two days ago, after I added separate functionality on the page, not effecting this code, and not importing any libraries or anything else, I got the error of

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '.fs.btn.heading.abstract' code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js:2`

AFTER a day of troubleshooting, I found that if i removed the `"'" +` and `+ "'"`, and it became `$(newClasses)`, the functionality started working again.  FYI: the variable `newClasses` did not include `'`s on either end of the string.

Now, I know this is somewhat of a different question, but what code could be added in a separate section to effect the functionality, and result in my having to remove the concatenation of the single quotes?

Notes -

- I am not looking for code help to the webpage, more troubleshooting methodology and thinking answers.
- due to the volume of code, and the different code that was added, it is pointless to post the code, but you can feel free to review the Git code [here](https://github.com/specialorange/ResumeBuilder)
- I even tried reverting to a prior commit, and for some reason, it still had the same error.
- I have deduced from my programming sessions that when the console refers to JS or JQuery on a low level line number (2 in this case), it usually has something to do with a trivial `;`, `)`, or `}`, but JSLint didn't show up that particular anomaly.
- no browser change since then, but I did reboot, and potentially had system updates waiting to finish.

Is it possible that the API of jQuery changed? something else that I'm not thinking of?  Your suggestions as to possible culprits is appreciated.

Comment: Why would you add single quotes to the string? A selector looks like, for example: `$("#foo .bar")` and you created `$("'#foo .bar'")`. That's simply invalid. If it worked, it was a bug. You are only need quotation marks for the attribute selector if the value contains special characters, for example: `$(".foo[bar='some value']")`.

Comment: The jQuery selector doesn't require apostrophes around the query. If it allowed it in the past then it was doing something odd/wrong.

Comment: Have you had a browser change recently?

Comment: I don't know how it ever worked. The `$` method takes a string. So you just needed to pass it your variable. You were adding `'` to the selector string, so it shouldnt have worked.

Comment: I did not add single quotes to the string, I added it to the parameter to be passed to the JQuery selector.   Assuming this is what you meant, I thought that this was needed, and as it worked for the first 2 months, I thought that it was ok.  I learned basic JQuery, and only used selectors with static names, but when I needed to select based on the class(es) of the clicked element, I fooled around and got it when I concatenated the variable with the `'`s on each end.  Hope that helps

Comment: Of course you added the quotes. `"'" + foo + "'"` is the same as `"'" + "some value" + "'"` is the same as `"'some value'"`. Quotation marks simply delimit a *string literal*, they are not part of the string itself. You can (most of the time) substitute literals with variables, like so: `$('.foo')` is the same as `var bar = '.foo'; $(bar);`.

Comment: can you explain a bit on what you mean `most of the time`, as maybe I changed something that effected one of those scenarios

Comment: If you cannot use variables as keys in object literals. I.e. you cannot change `var foo = {'bar': 42};` to `var baz = 'bar'; var foo = {baz: 42}`. The property name will be `baz`. But this is not really related to this problem.

Comment: One more thing regarding delimiters: Not only string literals have delimiters (`"foo"` or `'foo'`, `'` and `"`), also regex literals (`/foo/`, the `/`), array literals (`[42]`, `[` and `]`) and object literals (`{foo: 42}` , `{` and `}`). These delimiters help the parser to process the source correctly, but they are never part of the actual value. So when the parser sees a quotation mark it knows "ah, the characters up to the next matching quotation mark form a string". But through your string concatenation you actually made them part of the string, the value itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector is just a string.  If your variable is already a string type, then you don't need to add quotes to each end and doing so will probably cause an error as there are not supposed to be quotes on each end of the string.  So, `$(var)` should work just fine.

Quotes are used to declare a string literal like:

```
"#test"
```

but are not needed if you already have the data in a variable.  So, if you have a variable called `sel` that already contains the string `#test`, then you can just do:

```
$(sel)
```

The only time you might add quotes into a selector string is if you need quotes embedded into the middle of the string such as this selector:

```
[data-myval='whatever']
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know you ever used `$("'" + newClasses + "'")` in the first place.  Why are you adding `'` before and after the string?

That is like doing `$("'.fs.btn.heading.abstract'")`.  Which I can't see why you would have ever done.

The only time quotes are needed inside a jQuery selector is when you are using an attribute selector like: `$('input[id="test.input"]')`.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible you managed to make that code to work, the only possible explanation is that the code was never executed prior to adding that function.

What it is basically doing is:

```
var id= "#idname"; //#idname
var str = "'" + id + "'"; //'#idname'
$(str); //equivalent to $("'#idname'"); which is wrong
```

Remember that when you see `"hello"`, the string is holding only `hello`, the quotes are not part of the string